# JAXB Parsing Null

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to use jaxb to convert test XML to a POJO. I'm no longer getting any errors, it's just that the data is null. I was sure to add all the names to match case sensitivity and double check the tag names, but not sure why it's null.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserContainer.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
UserContainer users = (UserContainer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputFile);
```

Above is a snippet of code I am using to pull in the XML file from the static resources dir in Spring.

## XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<UserContainer>
  <description>Test User Data for Dev Database</description>
  <user>
    <username>user_1</username>
    <password>encrypted_password1</password>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <phone>4805551111</phone>
    <email>user1@gmail.com</email>
  </user>
  <user>
    <username>user_2</username>
    <password>encrypted_password2</password>
    <gender>female</gender>
    <phone>4805551111</phone>
    <email>user2@gmail.com</email>
  </user>
  <user>
    <username>user_3</username>
    <password>encrypted_password3</password>
    <gender>trans</gender>
    <phone>1113334454</phone>
    <email>user3@gmail.com</email>
  </user>
</UserContainer>
```

## UserContainer Class

```
import com.core.entities.User;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 * Allows a container to hold a list of users and map to standard POJO
 */
@XmlRootElement(name="UserContainer")
public class UserContainer {
  private List<User> users;

  public UserContainer() {}

  public UserContainer(List<User> users) {
    super();
    this.users = users;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
  }

  public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
  }
}
```

## User Class

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="user")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @XmlElement
  private String username;

  @XmlElement
  private String password;

  @XmlElement
  private String gender;

  @XmlElement
  private String phone;

  @XmlElement
  private String email;

  public User() {}

  public User(String username, String password, String gender, String phone, String email) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
  }

  public String getUserName() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUserName(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getEncryptedPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setEncryptedPassword(String encryptedPassword) {
    this.password = encryptedPassword;
  }

  public String getGender() {
    return gender;
  }

  public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
  }

  public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
  }

  public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a change in your UserContainer.java file like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="UserContainer")
public class UserContainer {

  @XmlElement(name="users")
  private List<User> users;

  public UserContainer() {}

  public UserContainer(List<User> users) {
    super();
    this.users = users;
  }
  public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
  }

  public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
  }
}
```

Also ideally you must have your XML Element with multi values like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<UserContainer>
  <description>Test User Data for Dev Database</description>
  <users>
      <user>
        <username>user_1</username>
        <password>encrypted_password1</password>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <phone>4805551111</phone>
        <email>user1@gmail.com</email>
      </user>
      <user>
        <username>user_2</username>
        <password>encrypted_password2</password>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <phone>4805551111</phone>
        <email>user2@gmail.com</email>
      </user>
      <user>
        <username>user_3</username>
        <password>encrypted_password3</password>
        <gender>trans</gender>
        <phone>1113334454</phone>
        <email>user3@gmail.com</email>
      </user>
  </users
</UserContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only change you need is add `name = "user"` to `@XmlElement` for `getUsers()`:

```
@XmlElement(name = "user")
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
```

---

There are many ways:

1. Add `@XmlElement(name = "user")` to `getUsers()` or `setUsers()` but not both:

   ```
   @XmlRootElement(name="UserContainer")
   public class UserContainer {
       private List<User> users;

       @XmlElement(name = "user")
       public List<User> getUsers() {
           return users;
       }

       public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
           this.users = users;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add `@XmlElement(name = "user")` to the field `users` and change [`@XmlAccessorType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorType.html) too [`FIELD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html#FIELD)

   ```
   @XmlRootElement(name="UserContainer")
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   public class UserContainer {
       @XmlElement(name = "user")
       private List<User> users;

       public List<User> getUsers() {
           return users;
       }

       public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
           this.users = users;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add `@XmlElement(name = "user")` to the field `users` and [`@XmlTransient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) to the public getter or setter.

   ```
   @XmlRootElement(name="UserContainer")
   public class UserContainer {
       @XmlElement(name = "user")
       private List<User> users;

       @XmlTransient
       public List<User> getUsers() {
           return users;
       }

       public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
           this.users = users;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Rename `getUsers` and `setUsers` into `getUser` and `setUser`:

   ```
   @XmlRootElement(name="UserContainer")
   public class UserContainer {
       private List<User> users;

       public List<User> getUser() {
           return users;
       }

       public void setUser(List<User> users) {
           this.users = users;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Does it actually matter if it goes on the getter or setter?

Comment: It seems like getter and setter are treated as a pair, so there should be no difference. Also see this question [What's the difference between JAXB annotations put on getter versus setters versus members?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22196082/8097737)

Comment: Actually still getting this error: Class has two properties of the same name "users"
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at public java.util.List com.habicus.repository.DataContainers.UserContainer.getUsers()
                at com.repository.DataContainers.UserContainer
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at private java.util.List com.repository.DataContainers.UserContainer.users
                at com.repository.DataContainers.UserContainer

Comment: added xmlaccesstype.field

Comment: You probably mixed my answer with the from [piy26](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49913124/8097737) and added `@XmlElement(name = "user")` to `private List<User> users;`. In this case you should change the [`@XmlAccessorType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorType.html) to [`FIELD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html#FIELD) or add [`@XmlTransient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) to the public getter or setter.